# Grovers algorithm: Diffuser on a state that isn't a linear superposition of all possible states

Tags: qiskit, grovers-algorithm

I've been trying to get Grover's algorithm to work, where part of the qubits have been measured, before Grovers is iterated. I have found a circuit that works, but I don't get why it does.

I have found [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.11163.pdf) paper, that explains how to build a general Grover's diffuser. They outline a circuit like this:

[image]

This seems logical to me.

I have tried implementing this, but it's behaving very weirdly:
[image]
I use the classically controlled Xs controlled on the output bit of that qubit to act as the "undo the measurement" and bring the qubits back to the state 00. This doesn't act like expected and just returns a linear superposition of all of the possible states of the last two qubits.

However, when I add two Hadamards after the classically controlled Xs, the circuit does produce the expected results as outlined by the oracle:
[image]

The oracle's unitary matrix looks like this:

```
[[-1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. -1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

Another problem that I have found with this circuit, is that when I put the first two qubits into a linear superposition using two Hadamards and then measure them, I get these results:
[image]
[image]

Please let me know if you need any more information!

Thanks for the help in advance,
Tom

Comment: I'm confused on the use of the starting measurements in the algorithm. Is it just to set the first two qubits to 0? If that were so the X's can be before the oracle and there's no need to have two more at the end conditional on the measurement. The paper doesn't mention anything related to a mid-computation measurement I can see.

Comment: What is the purpose of the measurement?

Note that the initial Hadamard (Unitary G) defines you construction of the database. If you perform a measurement before iterating, you implicitly change this "database state", and now you are only working on the collapsed substate. So your difussion and oracle needs to take that into account.

Comment: Im sorry for replying so late. The starting measurument is done, because the circuit had run grover's algorithm on those two qubits, before the beginning of this part of the circuit. Based on the outcome of this grovers, I need to adapt the amount of iterations. I have realized that using the measured qubits adds an additional degree of freedom, so instead Iǜe pivoted to keep them completely out of the iteration. I hope this makes things clearer. Thanks for the help!